# Converting a hex string into a BYTE array JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have been at this for a bit, and I am new to programing with JS.  I am making a game using JS, HTML5, node and socket.io.  I am working on the protocol right now and I am sending the server strings that are hex.

An example of a string would be: 00010203040506070809

I am having a hard time converting it to: 0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09

What I plan on doing is taking these custom packets and having a switch on my server based on the packets.  So for example:

```
BYTE HEADER | + Packet
0x00        | 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09
```

Then I call: parsepacket(header, data, len);

```
function parsepacket(header, data, len){
switch(header)
{
case '0x00':    // not hexed
console.log('The client wants to connect');
// Do some stuff to connect
break;

case '0x01':
console.log('0x01');
break;

case '0x02':
console.log('0x02!');
break;
}
};
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This might be useful: http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're after, but you can convert the string to an array of hex values like this:

```
var str = "00010203040506070809",
    a = [];

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i += 2) {
    a.push("0x" + str.substr(i, 2));
}

console.log(a); // prints the array
console.log(a.join(" ")); // turn the array into a string of hex values
​console.log(parseInt(a[1], 16));​ // parse a particular hex number to a decimal value
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted!  Bravo!  :-)

Comment: You don't need to add `0x` before an hexadecimal value to parse it.